# Is there a way to insert an image in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm very new to Xcode and Swift, so for now I'm creating a UI that requires an image to appear on the screen. I would like to add the image to the LaunchScreen.storyboard file in Xcode. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm very new to Xcode and Swift, so for now I'm creating a UI that requires an image to appear on the screen. I would like to add the image to the LaunchScreen.storyboard file in Xcode. Can anybody help me?

Images are typically stored in `.xcassets` files, which show up as folders in your project. Your project probably already has one called `Assets.xcassets`, and you can just drag and drop images into that file. Then you can add an image view to your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and set it to use the image you just added.

Beyond that, let me suggest that you go through some of Apple's [SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). They'll help you learn about Swift, but you'll also get a lot of exposure to just using Xcode. If you have to figure it all out on your own, it'll take a lot longer.